# R use apply across rows to find pattern

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to create a flag whether a certain code shows up in any cells in a given row of a dataset.  It needs to be an exact match - in other words if I'm looking for `'a1'` , `grep('a1', 'a123')` should return `false`.

Below is the code I'm attempting to use but not having any luck with.  It's just giving me the column numbers of the matching columns.

```
dfa <- data.frame(a = letters[1:10], b = letters[11:20], c = letters[5:14])
dfa$d = paste(dfa$a, dfa$b, sep = '')
vtc1 <- c('a','b','c', 'd')
for(i in vtc1){
    newColName <- paste(i,'_flag',sep = '')
    dfa[,newColName] <- apply(dfa[,vtc1], 1, function(x) as.numeric(grep(i, x, ignore.case = T)))
}
```

I'm trying to create a bunch of flag columns for each of the values in question.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: add word boundaries to your pattern `grep('\\ba1\\b', ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Add ^ and $ to your regexp. ^ indicates the start of the string, $ the end. 
`grepl()` gives a TRUE / FALSE vector

```
any(grepl(paste0("^", i "$"), x, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for exact match, change your function in apply to `length(which(x==i)`. Then I get the following output:

```
   a b c  d a_flag b_flag c_flag d_flag
1  a k e ak      1      0      0      0
2  b l f bl      0      1      0      0
3  c m g cm      0      0      1      0
4  d n h dn      0      0      0      1
5  e o i eo      0      0      0      0
6  f p j fp      0      0      0      0
7  g q k gq      0      0      0      0
8  h r l hr      0      0      0      0
9  i s m is      0      0      0      0
10 j t n jt      0      0      0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `stringr` for consistency of arguments and readability, and `data.table` to avoid using `apply` when doing `data.frame` operations as the syntax isn't particularly nice.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

dfa = setDT(dfa)
for(i in vtc1){
  dfa[, paste(i, "flag") := str_detect(paste(a, b, c, d),          # concatenate row
                                        paste0("\\b", i, "\\b"))]  # look for i
}

data.frame(dfa)
   a b c  d a.flag b.flag c.flag d.flag
1  a k e ak   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
2  b l f bl  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
3  c m g cm  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
4  d n h dn  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
5  e o i eo  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
6  f p j fp  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
7  g q k gq  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
8  h r l hr  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
9  i s m is  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
10 j t n jt  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

I'm not sure the test `data.frame` covered all cases, but hopefully it does what you're expecting.